# What version of the Office Apps add-in library should I use?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, apps-for-office

I've seen many examples and used the **1.1st version** for a long time but in [the new documentation](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn) they suddenly suggest including the **1st version** like so:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft Outlook Add-In won't initialize in **MAC** after updating the application to it's newest version. To fix this you need to **change the version of the Office App script you include in your add-in from 1.1 to 1.**

I now also found out Microsoft mentioning doing it in [the Dev Center Blog](https://dev.office.com/blogs/Office-Store-add-in-validation-changes-using-MicrosoftAjax-js):

> You may have seen examples that reference the /1.1/ resource,
>   https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js. That’s
>   fine for now but from now on, you should use the /1/ resource.